# Cloned(Clonezilla) a Dual Boot of Windows+Ubuntu but now GRUB Boots Ubuntu on wrong Drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, clone, clonezilla

I cloned Dual Boot of Windows+Ubuntu to another larger drive but now GRUB boots Ubuntu on the wrong drive.

When I choose to boot to windows, it boots just fine on the proper drive but that's not the case with ubuntu.

So, when I put BIOS to boot from the new drive's ubuntu, I choose ubuntu on GRUB and it boots on /dev/sdb2 instead of the new /dev/sda2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is awkward... I followed heynnema's answer and when I tried to boot into the drive it didn't change anything.

When I booted into the Live Ubuntu USB, via GParted I noticed that it didn't change the UUID.

Also doing

> sudo update-grub

Didn't work as I was in the live usb and couldn't do it on the target(new) drive as obviously I couldn't boot into it!

I fixed this all by using the *New UUID* option of GParted to change the UUID of the old drive.

Now all works as expected so thanks heynnema for giving me a huge pointer!

Comment: @heynnema while it pointed me to the right direction, it didn't work by itself.

Comment: If you add a screenshot of gparted view of the new drive to your question, I'll take a look and see if I can help with resizing the partitions.

Comment: @heynnema there's already one on superuser

Comment: You wanna give me a link...?

Comment: @heynnema https://superuser.com/q/1470091/471203

Comment: Looks like you already have an answer/solution there.

Comment: It's kind of a pseudo solution, if you have a better one I'd be happy to switch

Comment: Why don't you open a new question, since this is a new problem, create a current gparted screenshot, and we'll try and help there.

Answer (score 3):

After cloning your drive, normally you should normally remove one drive from the system. The reason is that both drives now have the same UUID's... the number that identifies the drives/partitions. When booting, either drive can answer up, 'causing it to boot to the "wrong" drive.

Also, understand, that a Clonezilla clone will probably NOT be restorable to the original drive, as Clonezilla clones only work when the target disk is LARGER than the source disk. Even one byte difference smaller and it won't restore.

If you wish to continue to have both drives connected, you'll have to change the UUID's on one of the drives.

You use four different commands to do this...

- `sudo blkid` # to view UUID's
- `sudo uuidgen -t` or `sudo uuidgen -r` # see `man uuidgen` for details
- `sudo tune2fs -U new_UUID /dev/sdxx` # see `man tune2fs` for details
- `sudo update-grub` # update grub with new UUID's

Be careful... if you change the UUID on the target boot drive, you'll need to edit `/etc/fstab` with the new UUID's.

You'll also want to adjust partition sizes on the new, larger drive, by using `gparted`. You can't change partition sizes on live/mounted partitions, so you've got to either boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, or unmount the partition(s) that you wish to resize.

Comment: So I supposed it's better if I change the UUID of the old drive?

Comment: @L3n  If you wish to keep BOTH drives installed (not recommended), and the goal was to clone the original disk to a newer, larger drive, then probably yes, you'd want to change UUID's on the old drive. You'll also want to adjust partition sizes on the new larger drive using `gparted`.

Comment: As for changing the size, well that's what I wish to do, but it's not letting me, on superuser I have a question about that

Comment: @L3n you can't edit/change partitions when you're booted to it, or the partitions are mounted live. You have to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and use `gparted`... or unmount the partition.

Comment: All this hassle is why I normally suggest a new clean install. Also does major housecleaning and can be quicker than the clone. After install, you then can copy /home, installed apps & maybe other settings from your backup. And if backup is missing anything, you still have old drive to go back to to improve your backup process.

Comment: @oldfred but... doing it your way... can you imagine the next AU question? *All the permissions/ownership is wrong on everything I manually copied over?* Cloning is the best/fastest way to migrate to a larger drive.

Comment: I posted another answer, thanks for helping either way, also I can't still change the size of the partitions even in a Live USB

Answer (score 0):

So I just cloned my dual boot hard drive, it took several attempts but I got it.  My set up was a 250 SSD GB dual boot windows 10/Unbuntu Studio 20.04 that I wanted cloned to a 500 GB SSD for more space.  The problem was if I used Macrium Reflect, windows would boot up, but Unbuntu would not, and if I used Clonezilla, Unbuntu would boot up, but Windows would not.  Macrium apparently has a problem with the Logical drive. I'm not sure what clonezilla's problem was.  My Source SSD had 4 partitions.

So I'll skip my multiple attempts and describe what worked...

I have two external USB cases - I left my source SSD in the laptop and put the target SSD in a USB external case and booted up Clonezilla from a USB stick I had created.  (Google how to get started with Clonezilla. You need to make a boot up disk or USB stick so that the source and target disks are offline during cloning)
I used Clonezilla to clone the entire disk, and let it resize proportionally, (as my target SSD was bigger) which made my Logical Volume about 200 GB which was what I wanted.  I could probably have just cloned the single Logical Volume Partition, but this kept the Logical Partition in the same spot as the 4th partition.  (I wasn't sure if it mattered what order the partitions were in, so I played it safe, I'm new at this)
I then removed my source SSD from my laptop and put it into my second USB external case, and plugged both into my Windows PC where I had Macrium Reflect loaded.
In Macrium Reflect, I was able to delete the 3 Primary partitions from the target disk leaving unallocated space to the left of the Logical Volume, and recloned just those 3 partitions from the source disk. (you can tell the Primary partitions from the Logical partitions easily when in Macrium.  they are labeled and colour coded)  In Macrium, if you drag the partitions you want to clone into position one at a time, you have the option to resize them individually before you drag the next one in. (You can only extend on the right, this makes sense when you have macrium open, there is an option to adjust each Target Partition before writing.  Macrium is pretty intuitive and user friendly).
Installed the 500 GB SSD in laptop and it's working perfectly:)